# how do I make jfilechooser only accept .txt

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I trying to save my contact in my table but filechosser always setit to all file.
is there way I can set it to accept .txt only and make it default or the only option.

```
savecontact.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser filesave = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = filesave.showSaveDialog(Main.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = filesave.getSelectedFile();

                PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(file);
                os.println("");
                for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                    os.print(table.getColumnName(col) + "\t");
                }
                os.println("");
                os.println("");

                for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        os.print(table.getColumnName(col));
                        os.print(": ");
                        os.println(table.getValueAt(row, col));
                    }
                    os.println("");
                }
                os.close();
                System.out.println("Done!");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You need to add a filter:

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
jf.setFileFilter(filter);
```

Comment: the code work but I still have to type in .txt extension to the end of the file. is there a way i can save it as .txt by default

Comment: After calling `File file = filesave.getSelectedFile();`, you can check whether the filename has the extension "txt".  If not, you create a new File object containing the extension and then continue with `new PrintWriter(file2);`  (Creating a new `File` object doesn't actually create the file.)

Comment: @Enwired By the look of the code - saving a table with `\t` delimiters for values in a row and new lines for rows, it should really be called `.tsv` (tab separated variable)!

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I agree in principle, but the question asker wanted to know how to force the file extension `.txt`.  I simply stated one way to do that.  He may have some reason why he prefers `.txt` over `.tsv`, and that is none of my business.  For example, Windows machines don't generally recognize the extension `.tsv`, though they do recognize `.csv`.

Comment: I was able to figure it after messing around with the code. thank for the help

Answer (score 23):

Here some examples

```
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp"));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.pdf", "pdf"));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.txt", "txt"));
```

Comment: is this will add all of the extension without removing the earlier filter added?

Answer (score 4):

You could do that by using [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters).

Create a `Filefilter` with the necessary conditions. Set this file filter to the `JFileChooser`, and launch it.