# Java FilenameExtensionFilter not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to make a utility in which user should be able to choose only ".pdf" files, nothing else. This is my code:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
       // jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
        jfc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.pdf", "pdf"));

        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

But the problem is that file chooser dialog also gives an "All files" option, which is ruining the work. I want user to select only .pdf files. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I make jfilechooser only accept .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771949/how-do-i-make-jfilechooser-only-accept-txt)

Comment: No, I'm still able to select .html, .txt and all other files along with pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing a problem like me, there is only one ray of hope.
Along with `FileNameExtensionFilter`, we have to use `JFileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);`.